# Using JSPServlet jsp-file without web.xml

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, servlet-3.0

I am trying to move from using Jetty with a web.xml to using embedded Jetty. I have managed to move my REST endpoints using HttpServletDispatchers however I am struggling to get the JSP servlet moved

Currently, in web.xml I have

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
```

The Java code I have is something like

```
final JspServlet indexServlet = new JspServlet();
final ServletHolder indexServletHolder = new ServletHolder("jsp", indexServlet);
indexServletHolder.setInitParameter("fork", "false");
indexServletHolder.setInitParameter("xpoweredBy", "false");
indexServletHolder.setInitOrder(1);

context.addServlet(indexServletHolder, "/*");
```

But I cannot work out where I would add the bit that related to

```
<jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
```

into Java

The index file is actually just a plain html page, so if there is an easier way to do this as not a JSP file, then that works too. I cannot put this file as a welcome file however, as I need all URL's to map to this one file (unless I can do that too and I am missing something)

Answer (score 1):

First, use [`JettyJspServlet`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.19.v20190610/apache-jsp/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/jsp/JettyJspServlet.java), not `JspServlet`.

See https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp

Your usage of `JettyJspServlet` will only be configured to recognize various jsp extensions (eg: a url-pattern of `*.jsp`), not directly attached to the `/index.jsp` (other servlet mappings will be your actual jsp files and references)

For a code equivalent of your web.xml segment of ...

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
```

it would be ...

```java
ServletHolder homeHolder = new ServletHolder();
homeHolder.setName("home");
homeHolder.setForcedPath("/index.jsp"); // equiv to <jsp-file>
context.addServlet(homeHolder, "/*");
```

... but this url-pattern is nonsense for a JSP file that's "all html".

This pattern means 100% of requests will go to your `/index.jsp`.

Please look at the example project, as setting up JSP in embedded-jetty is quite tricky!  Lots of things have to be in place *juuust* the right way before JSP will work properly.

You might be wanting to use the welcome-file behaviors, which will resolve (pay attention to this word!) against the requested URL if that requested URL would return a 404, the list of welcome files are attempted one after each other (using technique similar to `URI.resolve(String)` until one returns something other then a 404.

In the standard servlet descriptor `WEB-INF/web.xml` that would be represented in the following snippet ...

```xml
<web-app 
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
   metadata-complete="false"
   version="3.1"> 

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> <!-- relative ref -->
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file> <!-- absolute ref -->
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

or in code ...

```java
context.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.jsp", "/index.jsp", "index.html"});
```

Comment: 'but this url-pattern is nonsense for a JSP file that's "all html"' - how could I go about setting that all requests that don't map to a found resource map back to index.html? So favicon etc should return the correct thing, but /foo should show the index page still.

This was the only way I could get it to work in web.xml so that's just how it's been.

Comment: Thanks for this! This seems to be the correct direction for what I need, however this doesn't seem to resolve "/foo" to "index.html" if there is no file called "foo", but you're saying it should? So perhaps I have a config issue elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @joakim-erdfelt, I ended up using a welcome-list for the default index.html file, and then creating a custom ErrorHandler that on 404 errors which forwards the requests to /, which then, in turn, returns the index file.

Any request to localhost:8080 would correctly return the index.html page listed in welcomeFiles, but localhost:8080/foo would just return a 404 error

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(redirectRoute);
if (dispatcher != null && response.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND) {
    try {
        response.reset();
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        super.handle(target, baseRequest, request, response);
    }
} else if (response.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND) {
    logger.info("Can not redirect to /, no dispatcher found. Will show system 404 page");
} else {
    super.handle(target, baseRequest, request, response);
}
```

Comment: if you used `"index.jsp"` then a request to `localhost:8080/foo` would result in an internal request to `localhost:8080/foo/index.jsp`.  remember, think about how resolve works.  perhaps you meant to use `"/index.jsp"` instead?

Comment: My welcome file list included both "index.html" and "/index.html" and "/foo" still didn't seem to work

Comment: Looking at the source code for DefaultServlet, if seems that it does the check to see if the file exists before it checks the welcome list, so I cannot see how it is expected to work.
Within the doGet function it does a check for "// Not found?" first, and then continues on to "sendWelcome" if it was found